TSQL Stored procedure returning "string or binary data would be truncated" only when I try to insert the text "Date" or "DateTime"
So this issue is a real headscratcher for me.  I have the below TSQL Stored Procedure where I open a cursorDateField to work through setting up some fields for what will become a date dimension.  However, I noticed if I try to insert "Date" or "DateTime" into my temporary table during this event the Stored Procedure errors out with a "String or Binary Data would be Truncated" error.  However, if I enter something like "VARCHAR" it works fine.  If I make DateTime into "DateTimes" it works as well.  Same with Date, if I make it Dates it works.
My work around for the moment is I name the date field something like "Dates" and then after this ends I update the temporary table and change it to "Date".  Which also works.
So I'm hoping someone could explain what it is I'm doing wrong here.
My current code is below.  This code will error because this insert to has "Date" in it
        INSERT INTO @fields(Group_Name,Field_Name,Caption,Table_Name,Column_Name,Data_Type,Func, Form_Field_Name)
        VALUES(@groupName,@newCaption,@newCaption,@tableName,@columnName,'Date',@func,@formFieldName)



Create FUNCTION [FieldProc].[WhatIsGoingOnHere_TESTING]
(   
    @cubeName VARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS @fields TABLE (
    Field_ID VARCHAR(50),
    Group_Name VARCHAR(200),
    Field_Name VARCHAR(200),
    Caption VARCHAR(100),
    Table_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Column_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Data_Type VARCHAR(200),
    Sequence INT IDENTITY(1,100),
    Func VARCHAR(200),
    Sort_Type VARCHAR(50),
    Form_Field_Name VARCHAR(100),
    Display_Format VARCHAR(100),
    Sub_Display_Format VARCHAR(100),
    Aggregation_Type VARCHAR(50)

)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @fields(Field_ID,Group_Name,Field_Name,Caption,Table_Name,Column_Name,Data_Type) VALUES('','General','Create_DateTime','Create Time','vwTEST','Create_DateTime','DATETIME')


    DECLARE @groupName VARCHAR(50),@fieldName VARCHAR(50),@tableName VARCHAR(50),@columnName VARCHAR(100),@seq INT,@subSeq INT,@formFieldName varchar(100)
    DECLARE @caption VARCHAR(100),@func VARCHAR(200),@newCaption VARCHAR(200)


    DECLARE cursorDateField CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Group_Name, Field_Name, Caption, Table_Name,Column_Name, Sequence,Form_Field_Name 
    FROM @fields WHERE Data_Type IN ('Date','DateTime')

    OPEN cursorDateField

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorDateField INTO @groupName, @fieldName,@caption, @tableName,@columnName, @seq, @formFieldName
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @fields SET Data_Type='DATETIME',Sort_Type='Date' WHERE Field_Name=@fieldName

        SELECT @newCaption=@caption+' - Date', @subSeq=@seq+1,@func='CAST({fieldName}  AS date) '

        INSERT INTO @fields(Group_Name,Field_Name,Caption,Table_Name,Column_Name,Data_Type,Func, Form_Field_Name)
        VALUES(@groupName,@newCaption,@newCaption,@tableName,@columnName,'Date',@func,@formFieldName)

    
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorDateField INTO @groupName, @fieldName,@caption, @tableName,@columnName, @seq, @formFieldName

    END 

        
    CLOSE cursorDateField
    DEALLOCATE cursorDateField   

        RETURN;

END
GO

If I make this modification it will work but seems redundant to me


alter FUNCTION [FieldProc].[WhatIsGoingOnHere_TESTING]
(   
    @cubeName VARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS @fields TABLE (
    Field_ID VARCHAR(50),
    Group_Name VARCHAR(200),
    Field_Name VARCHAR(200),
    Caption VARCHAR(100),
    Table_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Column_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Data_Type VARCHAR(200),
    Sequence INT IDENTITY(1,100),
    Func VARCHAR(200),
    Sort_Type VARCHAR(50),
    Form_Field_Name VARCHAR(100),
    Display_Format VARCHAR(100),
    Sub_Display_Format VARCHAR(100),
    Aggregation_Type VARCHAR(50)

)
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @fields(Field_ID,Group_Name,Field_Name,Caption,Table_Name,Column_Name,Data_Type) VALUES('','General','Create_DateTime','Create Time','vsTEST','Create_DateTime','DATETIME')


    DECLARE @groupName VARCHAR(50),@fieldName VARCHAR(50),@tableName VARCHAR(50),@columnName VARCHAR(100),@seq INT,@subSeq INT,@formFieldName varchar(100)
    DECLARE @caption VARCHAR(100),@func VARCHAR(200),@newCaption VARCHAR(200)


    DECLARE cursorDateField CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT Group_Name, Field_Name, Caption, Table_Name,Column_Name, Sequence,Form_Field_Name 
    FROM @fields WHERE Data_Type IN ('Date','DateTime')

    OPEN cursorDateField

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorDateField INTO @groupName, @fieldName,@caption, @tableName,@columnName, @seq, @formFieldName
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @fields SET Data_Type='DATETIME',Sort_Type='Date' WHERE Field_Name=@fieldName

        SELECT @newCaption=@caption+' - Date', @subSeq=@seq+1,@func='CAST({fieldName}  AS date) '

        INSERT INTO @fields(Group_Name,Field_Name,Caption,Table_Name,Column_Name,Data_Type,Func, Form_Field_Name)
        VALUES(@groupName,@newCaption,@newCaption,@tableName,@columnName,'Dates',@func,@formFieldName)

    
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorDateField INTO @groupName, @fieldName,@caption, @tableName,@columnName, @seq, @formFieldName

    END 
    UPDATE @fields SET Data_Type = 'Date' WHERE Data_Type = 'Dates'
        
    CLOSE cursorDateField
    DEALLOCATE cursorDateField   

        RETURN;

END
GO


Looks like you've got an infinite loop going on there https://dbfiddle.uk/VehTBqq2 Why you need a cursor or an MSTVF is unclear, you almost certainly don't.
